# Swift compiler error: "Cannot invoke 'NSLog' with an argument list of type '(String, [CVarArgType])'"

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create custom wrapper for NSLog function using swift:

```
class func printLogMessage(format: String, _ args: CVarArgType...)
{
    NSLog(format, args: args)
}
```

But I get compiler error:

> Cannot invoke 'NSLog' with an argument list of type '(String,
>   [CVarArgType])'

Comment: In your case it would "simply" be `withVaList(args) { NSLogv(format, $0) }`.

Comment: I've searched according to error, so I don't think it is duplicate. Anyway thanks for reference and solution.

Comment: It looks like the same problem to me: How to pass `args: CVarArgType...` to  NSLog().